# copyright file in deb package - how to

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, dpkg

I'm trying to create a deb package from binaries but I have a problem with copyright file.
If I place a file named copyright inside DEBIAN folder it complains of two things:

- Missing copyright
- Unknown control file copyright

If I place it under `/usr/share/doc` or `/usr/share/doc/mypackage` it does not complain at all but, in any case, when I open generated debian package, Ubuntu Software Center states License: Unknown

Using: ubuntu raring

Executing `fakeroot dpkg-deb -z8 -Zgzip --build myproj`

Copyright file looks as follows:

```
Format: http://dep.debian.net/deps/dep5
Upstream-Name: myproj
Source:


Files: *
Copyright: 2013 myproj. All rights reserved.
License: Limited Use Software License Agreement
 License Text Here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the "Unknown" issue in Ubuntu Software Center is not an issue and cannot be solved for the moment.
From ubuntu lists, Feb'13 thread:

> Your copyright file looks perfect. Unfortunately, software-center
>   still doesn't actually parse the copyright file to gather that
>   information. It seems to use "License: Open Source" or everything in
>   Ubuntu main and universe, "Proprietary" for things in restricted, and
>   "Unknown" for everything else. There is an open bug report about the
>   issue here:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/435183

They started working in the issue in July

Answer (score 5):

if you build a package using *low-level* tools like `dpkg-deb` you should have a good knowledge on the internals of a debian package.

the `DEBIAN/`-folder is really *only* for control files, e.g. the `control` description file of the package, and various pre/post installation scripts (e.g. `postinst`).

otoh, the [usual way](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) to build packages is using *high-level* tools, namely `dpkg-buildpackage`, which uses a `debian/` directory, which has a similar name to `DEBIAN/` but is really something completely different (note the upper/lower case spelling).

`dpkg-buildpackage` (or rather it's underlying tools like `debhelper` or `cdbs` or whatever you choose) will install the `debian/changelog` file into `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>/`.
if you insist on using *low-level* tools, then you must not put your changelog into `DEBIAN/` but rather into `/usr/share/doc/myproj/`.

btw, you should use the DEP5-format described in it's [final version](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/) and also indicate that you did so using

```
Format: http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/
```

Comment: But from what I see dpkg-buildpackage is intended for packages that are going to be build with make, I want to create a package from binaries

Comment: `dpkg-buildpackage` knows nothing about `make` for *building* the package. (actually, it uses `make` internally to process the `debian/rules` file, but this is totally independent from (not) creating any files during the package's build process). e.g. a lot of packages contain only scripts, so no compilation is needed and the "source-files" can be used *as is*. still `dpkg-buildpackage` is used to assemble the package.