# Open source .deb package reported as proprietary

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I'm creating a `.deb` package for software that uses the Apache 2.0 license. Opening the `.deb` file in Ubuntu 17.10 wrongly reports in the license field "Proprietary". The package `copyright` file complies with the spec available from:

https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/

Notably, the `copyright` file `Files` section is:

```
Files: *
Copyright: 1998-2018 My Name
License: Apache-2.0
```

Any hints that you can share on what can be causing to package license to be incorrectly reported? The full `copyright` file is available at:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/14873a1a321b01b07f48da8f794130dcbc4ea1cf/scripts/debian/copyright

Comment: did you find a way to do it ? I find out from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/435183) that the Ubuntu Software Center says "License: Open Source" for everything in main and universe, "unknown" for things in multiverse and "proprietary" for things in restricted. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017084/copyright-file-in-deb-package-how-to which can help anyone who bump here.

Comment: @ponsfrilus I did found later that the `copyright` file is ignored. There's no attempt to parse it. Hopefully it would be solved soon. Thanks for the link to the other question.

Comment: Is this still an issue? E.g. this software is `open source`: https://github.com/klaussinani/tusk but in software center it is `Proprietary`